# Silently Skip Windows 7 UAC Prompts?

Tags: windows-7, security, permissions, uac

NOTE: I am **not** trying to disable UAC.

I have a Windows 7 machine where I've added one administrator account and one regular user account. When using the regular user account, a UAC dialog will show up having a password prompt when an application requires administrative privileges. Entering the administrator's password will allow the action to continue, but this is not the behavior that I require. Instead of prompting for the password, I would like the action to either silently fail (with the action logged in the system log) or show a permission denied dialog.

Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change how UAC acts in this scenario by using Security Policies:

Instructions [from here](http://resetchangewindows7password.com/prevent-standard-users-from-getting-windows-7-uac-administrators-passwords-prompts.htm):

> Follow these steps to eliminate UAC prompts for standard users:
>
> - Click on the start menu, type "secpol.msc" and hit Enter.
> - When the "Local Security Policy" editor ("snap-in") opens, double-click on "Local Policies" -for those affecting this particular
>     machine- and double-click on "Security Options".
> - Scroll down until you see a node labeled "User Account Control: Behavior of the Elevation Prompt for Standard Users" (careful, another
>     policy starts with the same name, but actually affects computer
>     administrators!) Double-click on it and the following dialog will
>     open:
>
> [image]
>
> - The default behavior for standard users, selected in the dropdown menu pictured above, is "Prompt for credentials": whenever elevated
>     privileges are required, they'll need to select an administrator and
>     enter its password in a UAC prompt to proceed with the action.
> - Click on the dropdown, and select the "Automatically deny elevation requests" option instead; click "OK" to apply the new setting: from
>     this point on, standard users won't event get a UAC prompt when they
>     attempt any task that needs administrative permissions.

See the link for extended information.

Comment: Ah, that's it! I figured it could be done in mmc somehow. Thanks a million.